# How to test React component with useParams?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to develop BBS App with TypeScript, React, React Router, React Testing Library, but a component with `useParams` doesn't pass a test. It looks like work correctly on the browser.

This is my component Thread.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import RedichanNav from 'RedichanNav';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'Thread.css';
import Stack from 'react-bootstrap/Stack';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import consola from 'consola';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

interface Post {
  id: number;
  poster: string;
  text: string;
  UTCTimeStamp: Date;
}

const Thread = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  // id's type is string | undefined.
  if (id === undefined) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected 'id' to be defined, but received undefined`);
  }

  const threadURI = `http://localhost:4000/api/thread/${id}`;

  const [thread, setThread] = useState(new Array<Post>());

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchThread = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(threadURI);
      const result = (await response.json()) as Array<Post>;
      setThread(result);
    };
    fetchThread().catch((err) => consola.error(err));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="Board mx-auto">
      <RedichanNav />
      <Stack className="mb-5">
        {thread.map((post, index) => (
          <Container key={post.id} className="bg-light border">
            <Row>
              <Col>{index}</Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col className="post-text">{post.text}</Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        ))}
        {/* br for layout. */}
        <br />
      </Stack>
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" fixed="bottom">
        <Nav className="ms-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="#post">➕</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Thread;
```

And my index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'index.css';
import Home from 'Home';
import Board from 'Board';
import Thread from 'Thread';
import reportWebVitals from 'reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/board/en/news" element={<Board name="enNews" />} />
      <Route path="/board/ja/news" element={<Board name="jaNews" />} />
      <Route path="/thread/:id" element={<Thread />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And my test Thread.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Thread from './Thread';

test('renders thread', () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/thread/0" element={<Thread />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  const post= screen.getByText('➕');

  expect(post).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

And I got

```
 FAIL  src/Thread.test.tsx
  ✕ renders thread (168 ms)

  ● renders thread

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: ➕. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

      13 |   );
      14 |
    > 15 |   const post= screen.getByText('➕');
         |                      ^
      16 |
      17 |   expect(post).toBeInTheDocument();
      18 | });

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at getByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Thread.test.tsx:15:22)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
```

It looks like the component is empty.

### Environment

- macOS 13.0
- Node.js 20.0.0
- TypeScript 4.8.4
- React 18.2.0
- React Router 6.4.3
- React Testing Library 8.19.0

Comment: Try using the `MemoryRouter` for testing instead of `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Thak you. I tried but got the same result.

Comment: Is the issue the odd text picture of the plus sign? If you targeted that element using a different method, like a `data-` attribute, does it still have the issue? Sorry, I should have also mentioned with the `MemoryRouter` you'll need to specify what the current URL path is so the correct content is rendered.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use MemoryRouter's initialEntries and now issue has been solved. Please post this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BrowserRouter` sort of depends on a DOM environment, i.e. like the browser, to function correctly. This doesn't work well in unit tests though. For unit testing we'll often use the `MemoryRouter` which uses its own `memoryHistory` object instead of relying on synchronizing with a browser's history stack.

Import the [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router) for use in unit tests to provide the routing context. Remember that the default initial entry is `"/"`, so if you have other routes you should also pass an `initialEntries` prop (*e.g. synonymous to a "history stack"*), and if necessary the `initialIndex` for the entry you want to render with. `initialIndex` defaults to the last entry of `initialEntries.

Example:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Thread from './Thread';

test('renders thread', () => {
  render(
    <Router initialEntries={["/thread/0"]}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/thread/:id" element={<Thread />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );

  const post= screen.getByText('➕');

  expect(post).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```